# Pitch accent for 金 (かね)

Tags: words

I can't find any sources to find the pitch accent of 金 (かね). Sorry for the basic question, but if anyone could tell me + where I can figure out the pitch accent of words (Other than OJAD) I would really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

It's heiban. かね{LH}.

E.g. かねがほしい{LHHLHL} = I want money.

I guess you know, but the standard source for accents is [日本語発音アクセント新辞典](https://www.nhk-book.co.jp/detail/000000113452016.html)
.

Comment: For actual sounds, one may try things like https://www.voicevox.su-shiki.com/ (seemingly unofficial web version of [Voicevox](https://voicevox.hiroshiba.jp/) ). Of course, it is not always correct and you'd often need to input sentences.